# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'ajaxSetup' of undefined

Tags: ajax, jquery

I'm having a problem in Chrome.  I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'ajaxSetup' of undefined

Here is my code:

```
function getRating(objId, holder) {
    if (!objId || !holder) {
        return;
    }
    $.ajaxSetup({cache: false});  // The error occurs here

    $.get('assets/components/lexrating/connector.php',{
        action: 'web/count/get',
        id: objId
    }, function(data) {
        var response = JSON.parse(data);
        if (response.object) {
            $(holder).rateit('value', response.object.value);
            var readonly = (response.object.allowedToVote === true) ? false : true;
            $(holder).rateit('readonly', readonly);
            var counterHolder = '#count_' + $(holder).prop('id');
            $(counterHolder).text(response.object['total.voters']);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Looks like you haven't included the jQuery library, or your code executes before the jQuery include.

Comment: In head - i'm included

src="/assets/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"
src="/assets/js/jquery-migrate-1.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"

2 part its code work - becouse i added [var $x=jQuery.noConflict();]

Comment: @user2553580: `var $x=jQuery.noConflict()`.  This line *removes* the `$` variable (restores it to its previous value).  You need to use `$x` instead.  `$x.ajaxSetup({cache: false});` and `$x.get()`.